# C#: Как подписаться на событие в статическим классе?

Tags: c#

В приложении используется пакет `NHotkey.Wpf` для назначения глобальных горячих клавиш.

Имеется статический класс с методом `public static void Enable()`, который добавляет заранее прописанные горячие клавиши.

**Проблема:** если такая клавиша уже будет зарегистрирована пользователем, то метод выдаст ошибку,  `NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyAlreadyRegistered`.

В обычном, нестатическом, классе я просто подписался на событие и перенаправляю его в виде текста об ошибке в консоль.

```cs
NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyManager.HotkeyAlreadyRegistered += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine("This Hotkey already registered!"); };
```

---

Где на это событие подписаться в статическом классе - я не понимаю, т.к. нет конструктора класса. Если добавить эту строку в начало метода `Enable()`, это тоже ничего не даст.

Я также пробовал подписаться на событие прямо в конструкторе `public App` в файле `App.xaml.cs`, но и это не помогло.

**Не уверен, что будет правильным исключать каждую отдельную горячую клавишу через `try-except`**.

---

**Код:**

```cs
static class Test
{
    public static void Enable()
    {

        NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyManager.HotkeyAlreadyRegistered += HotkeyManager_HotkeyAlreadyRegistered;

        NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyManager.Current.AddOrReplace("hotkey1", Key.Q, ModifierKeys.Control, (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine("hotkey1"); });
        NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyManager.Current.AddOrReplace("hotkey2", Key.W, ModifierKeys.Control, (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine("hotkey2"); });
        NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyManager.Current.AddOrReplace("hotkey3", Key.E, ModifierKeys.Control, (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine("hotkey3"); });
            . . . 
        // таких клавиш около 10 и прописывать try-catch для каждой кажется мне неуместным
    }

    private static void HotkeyManager_HotkeyAlreadyRegistered(object sender, NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyAlreadyRegisteredEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Клавиша уже зарегистрирована");
    }
}
```

Comment: Читайте исходники на гитхабе https://github.com/thomaslevesque/NHotkey/tree/master/src, очень многое станет понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через обработчик не получится, судя по тому, что я вижу в [исходниках](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/NHotkey/tree/master/src), обработчик события `HotkeyAlreadyRegistered` работает только с методом `AddKeyBinding`.

Поле `Name` нормально передается в исключение `HotkeyAlreadyRegisteredException`.

Чтобы не повторять код с исключениями, можно сделать коллекцию и цикл.

```
Key[] keys = new Key[] { Key.Q, Key.W, Key.E };
foreach (Key key in keys)
{
    try
    {
        NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyManager.Current.AddOrReplace($"Ctrl+{key}", key, ModifierKeys.Control, (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Name); });
    }
    catch (HotkeyAlreadyRegisteredException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hotkey '{ex.Name}' is already registered!");
    }
}
```

```
Hotkey 'Ctrl+Q' is already registered!
```

Comment: В примере из вопроса исключение через `NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyManager.HotkeyAlreadyRegistered += HotkeyManager_HotkeyAlreadyRegistered;` не срабатывает - метод не вызывается.

`try-catch` мне не подходит, потому что если хотя бы одна клавиша уже занята, другие все равно должны назначиться. А в `try-catch` первая строка с ошибкой завершит выполнение дальнейших строк. То есть нужно оборачивать в `try-catch` каждое добавление горячей клавиши отдельно?

Comment: То есть в моем примере обработчик `HotkeyManager_HotkeyAlreadyRegistered` просто не вызывается и не пишет в консоль "Клавиша уже зарегистрирована"

Comment: @denisnumb обновил ответ, хотя странно, что вы до него не догадались, если проблема только в этом была.

Comment: Да, вот это полностью подходит. Просто я не рассматривал вариант с try catch, так как хотел через обработчик. А вообще можно просто сделать еще один метод поверх `AddOrReplace` и уже в нем try catch. Но это тоже подойдёт, спасибо